# Determine why windows auth is failing for a BizTalk receive location

Tags: windows, permissions, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I've got a BizTalk receive location, pointed at a remote UNC file share, that when I turn on the receive location it immediately turns off, and complains it does not have read/write permissions on that directory. In the past when I have seen this, inevitably its because the BizTalk service account has not been given the 'full control' permission, or because of unix permission issues.

However, in this case it is a windows file server, with the BizTalk service account given full control over this directory. So neither one of these seems to be the issue. Plus, on another machine, I created a share, gave the service account permissions, both UNC and NTFS, pointed BizTalk it it, and it worked like a charm.

The only difference I can tell, is that they have given the group that the BizTalk service account is in, permissions higher up on in the directory structure. But that would simply imply that the service account has even a greater degree of permissions on that machine, not less.

- Any ideas what could be causing this?
- Is there any tools or such that could help track down a windows auth issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas what could be causing this?

Nothing immediately springs to mind however:

- I would change the directory permissions to be either Group perms or Service account perms for consistency.
- You mentioned UNC Share and NTFS perms in your post and I would double check those on your problematic share to make sure they consistent with the Group or Service Account perms.
- I would also check to ensure that the BizTalk Host running your FILE Adapter is using the credentials you expect it to be using, and is a member of the expected group.

If these checks don't work, I would consider setting the FILE Adapter to use different authentication credentials - to something you know that works - over-riding the BizTalk Service credentials to discount BizTalk being the problem.

> Are there any tools or such that could help track down a windows auth issue?

With regards to tools, I'm not aware of anything to help with this specific problem, however [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/bb896653) from SysInternals might offer some insight into what is going on.